# Quine program without main()

Tags: java, enums, quine

I came across this [little quine program](http://www.reficio.org/2010/01/25/hardcore-java-quine-and-backward-quine/), written without main method:

```
enum f {
  f;
  System z;
  String s="enum f{f;System z;String s=%c%s%1$c;{z.out.printf(s,34,s);z.exit(0);}}";
  {z.out.printf(s,34,s);
  z.exit(0);}
}
```

Can somebody explain how does this work? Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, but how do you let it run? EDIT: The file has to be named `f.java`, so you compile it with `javac f.java`

Comment: Yes. You compile it with `javac f.java` and run it with `java f`. It works with jdk6, but not with 7.

Comment: After I've read the description you posted, I got it running, thanks nevertheless :)

Comment: @mtsz Up to at least Java 6 you could run classes without a `main` method, but with a static initializer; the JVM would complain about the missing method, but after loading the class, which would execute the static initializer. I just tried it out with Java 7 and it complains immediately, before running the static initializer. Looks like this is a change in Java 7.

Comment: Thanks @Jesper, I didn't know it was even possible to run code with only a static initializer. It's always great to learn something new :)

Comment: Fun fact: Java WebStart also loads the main class without initialising it, so wont run the static initialiser if the main method is not present.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lines 5 and 6 are an [instance initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). It is called when the class is instantiated. Since this is an enum with one constant named `f`, it is going to be instantiated once and the instance initializer block is executed.

Note that `z` is `null`, but `out` is a static member of class `System`, so you can call `z.out.printf()` anyway. The `printf` statement takes the string `s` as a format string with two arguments, `34` and `s` itself.

`34` is the ASCII code for double quote `"`. It is filled in for the `%c` and `%1$c` in the format string. The `%s` in the format string is replaced by the format string `s` itself.